# How to increment the cell reference in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am calculating sum for multiple sheets in a workbook
formula is as below

=SUM('Sheet1'!C11,'Sheet2'!C10,'Sheet3'!C11,'Sheet4'!C14)

The values being added are horizontal
I tried adding $ sign infront of C11 it didnt work

I want to increment only Alphabet i.e C11 to D11 to AH11
C10 to D10 to AH10

=SUM('Sheet1'!D11,'Sheet2'!D10,'Sheet3'!D11,'Sheet4'!D14)

How do I achieve that?

Comment: And how are you dragging this? Horizontal or downwards?

Comment: dragging down vertically

Comment: =SUM('Sheet1'!D$11,'Sheet2'!D$10,'Sheet3'!D$11,'Sheet4'!D$14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use (as your starting formula):

```
=SUM(INDEX(Sheet1!$11:$11,ROW(A3)),INDEX(Sheet2!$10:$10,ROW(A3)),INDEX(Sheet3!$11:$11,ROW(A3)),INDEX(Sheet4!$14:$14,ROW(A3)))
```

And drag down.

Comment: Hi, Can u explain the significance of Row(A3)? I understand that it gives row number back, if I change it to A2, which is were Im starting to input the values and drag down. the results dont macth

Comment: Its important to tell `INDEX` to start giving back from column 3 onwards. Note `ROW(A3)` returns '3'!. So you can just put the above formula in A2. And drag down. Sidenote, if this has worked. Don't forget to actually accept the answer. I seen on your profile you should also re-visit your older question and see if you can accept/upvote an answer that worked for you. It's simple courtesy. if you are unfamiliar with the concept, you could take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Can you look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62794417/how-to-update-values-automatically-from-sheet-to-another